# Fetching columns where at least two rows have values

Tags: sql

To firstly introduce the table, it's a table where a date occurs 4 times. With 4 different times. Those times are always the same. It has to do with personal workouts.

The result I want is that I want to know how many workouts I have done. A workout is only complete when at least 2 rows have a BPM on a certain date.

[see image]

For example; I've had a workout on 20-07-2022. You can see that because time 18:30, 20:00, 20:30 and 23:59 have a BPM.

I didn't have a workout on 21-07-2022, because only one BPM occurs (23:59)

[image: Table example]

I understand that I have to do something with GROUPING and checking if BPM is not NULL. But I have to do that for at least 2 rows for each date.

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pm_transformation WHERE bpm > 0 GROUP BY datum");
$stmt->execute();
$workouts = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

But this obviously doesn't work, I just don't know how to approach this SQL.

The expected result for this image is: **3** workouts.

**Edit:** 20-07-2022, 22-07-2022 and 23-07-2022 because they have more than 1 BPM for each date.

If there are any questions, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're storing dates in some custom format. Dates should be stored in a column with the type `date` (which has the format `Y-m-d`) and time should be stored in a column with the type `time`. I would even put both the date and the time in the same column, using the type `datetime`. Storing dates (I assume as `varchar`) in the format you have makes it much harder to sort the dates (since MySQL will see them as strings).

Comment: @M.Eriksson I see, so I changed that. What would the approach be than? [See image](https://cdn.patrickmid.nl/20220727134940.png)

Comment: I don't see how this question related to php

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 select datum from pm_transformation where datum in 
    (select datum from pm_transformation 
    where bpm is not NULL 
    group by datum having count(*) > 1) group by datum
```

You can't have an aggregate in a where clause, but you can use a having clause instead. This should give you the dates on which you had workouts.